# Javascript with dropdown to show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone look at my code, something is not working, this is my first java based on some tutorials but for some reason is not working, i put it in a php file and uploaded to my server then i doest work anymore. i checked it in JSFddle and it was working.

```
<head>  
 <style type="text/css">
.div1 {color: red; display:none}
.div2 {color: blue; display:none}
.div3 {color: red; display:none}
.div4 {color: blue; display:none}
.div5 {color: red; display:none}
</style>  

<script type"text/javascript" src="//http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type"text/javascript">
$("#cities").change(function(){
  var value = this.value;
  if (value == "1"){
    $(".div1").show();
    $(".div2").hide();
    $(".div3").hide();
    $(".div4").hide();
    $(".div5").hide();
  }else if (value == "2"){
    $(".div1").hide();
    $(".div2").show();
    $(".div3").hide();
    $(".div4").hide();
    $(".div5").hide();
  }else if (value == "3"){
    $(".div1").hide();
    $(".div2").hide();
    $(".div3").show();
    $(".div4").hide();
    $(".div5").hide();
  }      
});
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<select class="cities" id="cities" name="project_procurement_management_plan[items_attributes][0][category_id]">
<option value="">select one</option>
<option value="1">this is 1</option>
<option value="2">this is 2</option>
<option value="3">this is 3</option>
</select>
<hr>
<div class="div1">1</div>
<div class="div2">2</div>
<div class="div3">3</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script type tag has problem, change

```
<script type"text/javascript">
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

and place your entire `.change()` code inside [DOM ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#cities").change(function(){
      //rest of your code
   });
});
```

and remove `//` at start, from jQuery url as well

Comment: where i suppose to add .change() im very new to this.

Comment: @Wrostran you need to wrap .change() code inside $(document).ready() { ... your .change() code in here.. }); as in answer above

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
<script type"text/javascript" src="//http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script type"text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You have two unnecessary forward slashes at the beginning.